# Partition: show in user interface is turned off, yet it shows up in nautilus

Tags: partitioning, nautilus

I have a partition that doesn't want to behave. I turned off ["Show in user interface"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWEa5.png) for that (and every other) partition in Disks. However, this one particular partition [still shows up in Nautilus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZC8K.png) (the others don't). I'm not a newbie, but not a expert Linux user either.

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 Focal Fossa, and I can provide any other information you may require.

Edit 1:  the contents of my [/etc/fstab](https://pastebin.com/KsiUNuQj) as requested

Comment: Show the contents of `/etc/fstab`. An easy "workaround" would be to mount the drive outside of your home partition, then access it through a symlink.

Comment: Could this be because it is mounted directly inside home? I have 2 other partitions mounted inside /home/Documents/, they are working just fine.

Comment: Normally, devices under $HOME are shown, so I do not see why the others under your home actually are not showing. Try whether it wants to hide with the option `x-gvfs-hide`. This should explicitly indicate the device should not be shown.

Comment: I will try that as soon as I am able to. However, I just had a thought: is it possible that it shows up, because I bind a folder somewhere into the partition  (namely: PersonalData/Plex)? and if so, should I add x-gvfs-hide to that line too?

Comment: Thank you very much for your help @vanadium. I posted an answer so we can close this down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `x-gvfs-hide` in `/etc/fstab` did hide the partition in Nautilus.

Just to be clear, before it looked like this:

`/dev/disk/by-id/wwn-0x50014ee2070eeb62-part2 /home/wolfi/PersonalData auto nosuid,nodev,nofail 0 0`

And after I put `x-gvfs-hide` in:

`/dev/disk/by-id/wwn-0x50014ee2070eeb62-part2 /home/wolfi/PersonalData auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-hide 0 0`